# [android studio]having problem with handler.postdelayed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hope you doing great.i'm very new to android programming and i have source of an app which i intend to modify and add [PatternLockView](https://github.com/aritraroy/PatternLockView) library to it . i watched a [youtube video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYYFelIdZsQ&t) but i can't use handler.postdelay option in the code (android studio returns with : Cannot resolve symbol 'postdelayed').the coder who made the tutorial didn't got any errors or so but android studio gives me [lots of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhAIR.png) . any help or hint is appreciated.
here is the code :

```
Handler handler = new Handler ();
    handler.postdelayed {
        @Override
        public void run()  {
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
            String password = preferences.getString("password","0");
            if (password.equals("0")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),CreatePasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),InputPasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }

    }2000
```

---

```
    /*#######################################################
 *
 *   Maintained by Gregor Santner, 2017-
 *   https://gsantner.net/
 *
 *   License of this file: Apache 2.0 (Commercial upon request)
 *     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
#########################################################*/
package net.gsantner.markor.activity;
 
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
 
import com.pixplicity.generate.Rate;
 
import net.gsantner.markor.BuildConfig;
import net.gsantner.markor.R;
import net.gsantner.markor.format.TextFormat;
import net.gsantner.markor.ui.FilesystemViewerCreator;
import net.gsantner.markor.ui.NewFileDialog;
import net.gsantner.markor.util.ActivityUtils;
import net.gsantner.markor.util.AppSettings;
import net.gsantner.markor.util.PermissionChecker;
import net.gsantner.markor.util.ShareUtil;
import net.gsantner.opoc.activity.GsFragmentBase;
import net.gsantner.opoc.format.markdown.SimpleMarkdownParser;
import net.gsantner.opoc.ui.FilesystemViewerAdapter;
import net.gsantner.opoc.ui.FilesystemViewerData;
import net.gsantner.opoc.ui.FilesystemViewerFragment;
 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import butterknife.OnLongClick;
import butterknife.OnPageChange;
 
public class MainActivity extends AppActivityBase implements FilesystemViewerFragment.FilesystemFragmentOptionsListener, BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    //START
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed( () -> {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        String password = preferences.getString("password","0");
        if (password.equals("0")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),CreatePasswordActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),InputPasswordActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 2000);
// END
    public static boolean IS_DEBUG_ENABLED = false;
 
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    public Toolbar _toolbar;
 
    @BindView(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar)
    BottomNavigationView _bottomNav;
 
    @BindView(R.id.fab_add_new_item)
    FloatingActionButton _fab;
 
    @BindView(R.id.main__view_pager_container)
    ViewPager _viewPager;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter _viewPagerAdapter;
 
    private boolean _doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;
    private MenuItem _lastBottomMenuItem;
 
    private AppSettings _appSettings;
    private ActivityUtils _contextUtils;
    private ShareUtil _shareUtil;
 
    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setExitTransition(null);
        }
        _appSettings = new AppSettings(this);
        _contextUtils = new ActivityUtils(this);
        _shareUtil = new ShareUtil(this);
        _contextUtils.setAppLanguage(_appSettings.getLanguage());
        if (_appSettings.isOverviewStatusBarHidden()) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setTheme(_appSettings.isDarkThemeEnabled() ? R.style.AppTheme_Dark : R.style.AppTheme_Light);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main__activity);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
        _toolbar.setOnClickListener(this::onToolbarTitleClicked);
 
        optShowRate();
 
        try {
            if (_appSettings.isAppCurrentVersionFirstStart(true)) {
                SimpleMarkdownParser smp = SimpleMarkdownParser.get().setDefaultSmpFilter(SimpleMarkdownParser.FILTER_ANDROID_TEXTVIEW);
                String html = "";
                html += smp.parse(getString(R.string.copyright_license_text_official).replace("\n", "  \n"), "").getHtml();
                html += "<br/><br/><br/><big><big>" + getString(R.string.changelog) + "</big></big><br/>" + smp.parse(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.changelog), "", SimpleMarkdownParser.FILTER_ANDROID_TEXTVIEW);
                html += "<br/><br/><br/><big><big>" + getString(R.string.licenses) + "</big></big><br/>" + smp.parse(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.licenses_3rd_party), "").getHtml();
                ActivityUtils _au = new ActivityUtils(this);
                _au.showDialogWithHtmlTextView(0, html);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        IntroActivity.optStart(this);
 
        // Setup viewpager
        _viewPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        _viewPager.setAdapter(_viewPagerAdapter);
        _viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        _bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
 
        // noinspection PointlessBooleanExpression - Send Test intent
        if (BuildConfig.IS_TEST_BUILD && false) {
            DocumentActivity.launch(this, new File("/sdcard/Documents/mordor/aa-beamer.md"), false, true, null, null);
        }
 
        (new ActivityUtils(this)).applySpecialLaunchersVisibility(_appSettings.isSpecialFileLaunchersEnabled());
 
        _bottomNav.postDelayed(() -> {
            if (_appSettings.getAppStartupTab() != R.id.nav_notebook) {
                _bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(_appSettings.getAppStartupTab());
            }
        }, 1);
    }
 
    private void optShowRate() {
        new Rate.Builder(this)
                .setTriggerCount(4)
                .setMinimumInstallTime((int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(30))
                .setFeedbackAction(() -> new ActivityUtils(this).showGooglePlayEntryForThisApp())
                .build().count().showRequest();
    }
 
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        PermissionChecker permc = new PermissionChecker(this);
        permc.checkPermissionResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
 
 
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        AppSettings as = new AppSettings(this);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_preview: {
                File f = _bottomNav.getSelectedItemId() == R.id.nav_quicknote ? as.getQuickNoteFile() : as.getTodoFile();
                DocumentActivity.launch(MainActivity.this, f, false, true, null, null);
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.action_settings: {
                new ActivityUtils(this).animateToActivity(SettingsActivity.class, false, null);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
 
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main__menu, menu);
 
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(_appSettings.isShowSettingsOptionInMainToolbar());
 
        _contextUtils.tintMenuItems(menu, true, Color.WHITE);
        _contextUtils.setSubMenuIconsVisiblity(menu, true);
        return true;
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        //new AndroidSupportMeWrapper(this).mainOnResume();
        super.onResume();
        IS_DEBUG_ENABLED = BuildConfig.IS_TEST_BUILD;
        if (_appSettings.isRecreateMainRequired()) {
            // recreate(); // does not remake fragments
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
 
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && _appSettings.isMultiWindowEnabled()) {
            setTaskDescription(new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(getString(R.string.app_name)));
        }
 
        int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, _appSettings.isDarkThemeEnabled()
                ? R.color.dark__background : R.color.light__background);
        _viewPager.getRootView().setBackgroundColor(color);
 
        if (_appSettings.isKeepScreenOn()) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        } else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Determine some results and forward using Local Broadcast
        Object result = _shareUtil.extractResultFromActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, this);
 
 
        try {
            FilesystemViewerFragment frag = (FilesystemViewerFragment) _viewPagerAdapter.getFragmentByTag(FilesystemViewerFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
            frag.getAdapter().reconfigure();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            recreate();
        }
    }
 
    @OnLongClick({R.id.fab_add_new_item})
    public boolean onLongClickFab(View view) {
        PermissionChecker permc = new PermissionChecker(this);
        FilesystemViewerFragment fsFrag = (FilesystemViewerFragment) _viewPagerAdapter.getFragmentByTag(FilesystemViewerFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (fsFrag != null && permc.mkdirIfStoragePermissionGranted()) {
            fsFrag.getAdapter().setCurrentFolder(fsFrag.getCurrentFolder().equals(FilesystemViewerAdapter.VIRTUAL_STORAGE_RECENTS)
                            ? FilesystemViewerAdapter.VIRTUAL_STORAGE_FAVOURITE : FilesystemViewerAdapter.VIRTUAL_STORAGE_RECENTS
                    , true);
        }
        return true;
    }
 
    @SuppressWarnings("SwitchStatementWithTooFewBranches")
    @OnClick({R.id.fab_add_new_item})
    public void onClickFab(View view) {
        PermissionChecker permc = new PermissionChecker(this);
        FilesystemViewerFragment fsFrag = (FilesystemViewerFragment) _viewPagerAdapter.getFragmentByTag(FilesystemViewerFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (fsFrag == null) {
            return;
        }
 
        if (fsFrag.getAdapter().isCurrentFolderVirtual()) {
            fsFrag.getAdapter().loadFolder(_appSettings.getNotebookDirectory());
            return;
        }
        if (permc.mkdirIfStoragePermissionGranted()) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.fab_add_new_item: {
                    if (_shareUtil.isUnderStorageAccessFolder(fsFrag.getCurrentFolder()) && _shareUtil.getStorageAccessFrameworkTreeUri() == null) {
                        _shareUtil.showMountSdDialog(this);
                        return;
                    }
 
                    if (!fsFrag.getAdapter().isCurrentFolderWriteable()) {
                        return;
                    }
 
                    NewFileDialog dialog = NewFileDialog.newInstance(fsFrag.getCurrentFolder(), true, (ok, f) -> {
                        if (ok) {
                            if (f.isFile()) {
                                DocumentActivity.launch(MainActivity.this, f, false, false, null, null);
                            } else if (f.isDirectory()) {
                                FilesystemViewerFragment wrFragment = (FilesystemViewerFragment) _viewPagerAdapter.getFragmentByTag(FilesystemViewerFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
                                if (wrFragment != null) {
                                    wrFragment.reloadCurrentFolder();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), NewFileDialog.FRAGMENT_TAG);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Exit confirmed with 2xBack
        if (_doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            _appSettings.setFileBrowserLastBrowsedFolder(_appSettings.getNotebookDirectory());
            return;
        }
 
        // Check if fragment handled back press
        GsFragmentBase frag = _viewPagerAdapter.getCachedFragments().get(_viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        if (frag != null && frag.onBackPressed()) {
            return;
        }
 
        // Confirm exit with back / snackbar
        _doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        new ActivityUtils(this).showSnackBar(R.string.press_back_again_to_exit, false, R.string.exit, view -> finish());
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> _doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false, 2000);
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        updateFabVisibility(item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_notebook);
        PermissionChecker permc = new PermissionChecker(this);
 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_notebook: {
                _viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                _toolbar.setTitle(getFileBrowserTitle());
                return true;
            }
 
            case R.id.nav_todo: {
                permc.doIfExtStoragePermissionGranted(); // cannot prevent bottom tab selection
                restoreDefaultToolbar();
                _viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                _toolbar.setTitle(R.string.todo);
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.nav_quicknote: {
                permc.doIfExtStoragePermissionGranted(); // cannot prevent bottom tab selection
                restoreDefaultToolbar();
                _viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                _toolbar.setTitle(R.string.quicknote);
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.nav_more: {
                restoreDefaultToolbar();
                _viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                _toolbar.setTitle(R.string.more);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
 
    public void updateFabVisibility(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            _fab.show();
        } else {
            _fab.hide();
        }
    }
 
    public String getFileBrowserTitle() {
        final File file = _appSettings.getFileBrowserLastBrowsedFolder();
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        if (!_appSettings.getNotebookDirectory().getAbsolutePath().equals(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
            title = "> " + file.getName();
        }
        return title;
    }
 
    @OnPageChange(value = R.id.main__view_pager_container, callback = OnPageChange.Callback.PAGE_SELECTED)
    public void onViewPagerPageSelected(int pos) {
        Menu menu = _bottomNav.getMenu();
        PermissionChecker permc = new PermissionChecker(this);
        (_lastBottomMenuItem != null ? _lastBottomMenuItem : menu.getItem(0)).setChecked(false);
        _lastBottomMenuItem = menu.getItem(pos).setChecked(true);
        updateFabVisibility(pos == 0);
        _toolbar.setTitle(new String[]{getFileBrowserTitle(), getString(R.string.todo), getString(R.string.quicknote), getString(R.string.more)}[pos]);
 
        if (pos > 0 && pos < 3) {
            permc.doIfExtStoragePermissionGranted(); // cannot prevent bottom tab selection
        }
    }
 
    private FilesystemViewerData.Options _filesystemDialogOptions = null;
 
    @Override
    public FilesystemViewerData.Options getFilesystemFragmentOptions(FilesystemViewerData.Options existingOptions) {
        if (_filesystemDialogOptions == null) {
            _filesystemDialogOptions = FilesystemViewerCreator.prepareFsViewerOpts(getApplicationContext(), false, new FilesystemViewerData.SelectionListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onFsViewerConfig(FilesystemViewerData.Options dopt) {
                    dopt.descModtimeInsteadOfParent = true;
                    //opt.rootFolder = _appSettings.getNotebookDirectory();
                    dopt.rootFolder = _appSettings.getFolderToLoadByMenuId(_appSettings.getAppStartupFolderMenuId());
                    dopt.folderFirst = _appSettings.isFilesystemListFolderFirst();
                    dopt.doSelectMultiple = dopt.doSelectFolder = dopt.doSelectFile = true;
                    dopt.mountedStorageFolder = _shareUtil.getStorageAccessFolder();
                    dopt.showDotFiles = _appSettings.isShowDotFiles();
                    dopt.fileComparable = FilesystemViewerFragment.sortFolder(null);
                }
 
                @Override
                public void onFsViewerDoUiUpdate(FilesystemViewerAdapter adapter) {
                    if (adapter != null && adapter.getCurrentFolder() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(adapter.getCurrentFolder().getName())) {
                        _appSettings.setFileBrowserLastBrowsedFolder(adapter.getCurrentFolder());
                        _toolbar.setTitle(adapter.areItemsSelected() ? "" : getFileBrowserTitle());
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
 
                        if (adapter.getCurrentFolder().equals(FilesystemViewerAdapter.VIRTUAL_STORAGE_FAVOURITE)) {
                            adapter.getFsOptions().favouriteFiles = _appSettings.getFavouriteFiles();
                        }
                    }
                }
 
                @Override
                public void onFsViewerSelected(String request, File file, final Integer lineNumber) {
                    if (TextFormat.isTextFile(file)) {
                        DocumentActivity.launch(MainActivity.this, file, false, null, null, lineNumber);
                    } else if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".apk")) {
                        _shareUtil.requestApkInstallation(file);
                    } else {
                        DocumentActivity.askUserIfWantsToOpenFileInThisApp(MainActivity.this, file);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return _filesystemDialogOptions;
    }
 
    class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private HashMap<Integer, GsFragmentBase> _fragCache = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 
        SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragMgr) {
            super(fragMgr);
        }
 
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            GsFragmentBase fragment = (GsFragmentBase) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            _fragCache.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }
 
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            final Fragment existing = _fragCache.get(pos);
            if (existing != null) {
                return existing;
            }
 
            switch (_bottomNav.getMenu().getItem(pos).getItemId()) {
                default:
                case R.id.nav_notebook: {
                    return FilesystemViewerFragment.newInstance(getFilesystemFragmentOptions(null));
                }
                case R.id.nav_quicknote: {
                    return DocumentEditFragment.newInstance(_appSettings.getQuickNoteFile(), false, -1);
                }
                case R.id.nav_todo: {
                    return DocumentEditFragment.newInstance(_appSettings.getTodoFile(), false, -1);
                }
                case R.id.nav_more: {
                    return MoreFragment.newInstance();
                }
            }
        }
 
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
            _fragCache.remove(position);
        }
 
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return _bottomNav.getMenu().size();
        }
 
        public GsFragmentBase getFragmentByTag(String fragmentTag) {
            for (GsFragmentBase frag : _fragCache.values()) {
                if (fragmentTag.equals(frag.getFragmentTag())) {
                    return frag;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
 
        public HashMap<Integer, GsFragmentBase> getCachedFragments() {
            return _fragCache;
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
 
        restoreDefaultToolbar();
    }
 
    /**
     * Restores the default toolbar. Used when changing the tab or moving to another activity
     * while {@link FilesystemViewerFragment} action mode is active (e.g. when renaming a file)
     */
    private void restoreDefaultToolbar() {
        FilesystemViewerFragment wrFragment = (FilesystemViewerFragment) _viewPagerAdapter.getFragmentByTag(FilesystemViewerFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (wrFragment != null) {
            wrFragment.clearSelection();
        }
    }
 
    private void onToolbarTitleClicked(View v) {
        Fragment f = _viewPagerAdapter.getItem(_viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        if (f instanceof DocumentEditFragment) {
            DocumentEditFragment def = (DocumentEditFragment) f;
            def.onToolbarTitleClicked(_toolbar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed the spelling but unfortunately didn't made any change.tried the suggestions on that post but they didn't made any difference either.

Comment: Have you downvoted my answer?

Comment: no i didn't.someone even down voted the original question.

Comment: I see, updated the code check it out!

Comment: I recommend you that you use Android Studio while coding. Its intellisense feature helps developers a lot for code completion. It makes things much easier and helps write less error prone code especially while coding the APIs.

Comment: i'm using it i just don't understand why for the original maker of the video these errors didn't show up . i did everything exactly like him.

Comment: Consider adding the whole source code that includes this piece of code.

Comment: i added it to original post as a pastebin link.

Comment: Hey, the page is not loading. Is the link correct?

Comment: nvm.i just aded to code to the post.

Comment: My friend, move your piece of code in to the `onCreate` method of the Activity. That code does not belong to the class definition context because it is an executable.

Comment: man thank you!you are awesome thank you very much!now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `postDelayed` is a method, you have to use `()` along with it. It takes 2 parameters, first one is a `Runnable` object and second one is a millisecond value to delay which is an `int` type. Also `Handler()` constructor is [depracated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#public-constructors_1), that's why you have to bind your handler to a looper object, commonly to the main looper. Here is the fixed code:

```java
// Make sure you import the right Handler class
import android.os.Handler;

Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed( () -> {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        String password = preferences.getString("password","0");
        if (password.equals("0")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),CreatePasswordActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),InputPasswordActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, millisecondDelay);
```

**UPDATE**
I've noted that your `postdelayed` syntax isn't correct. It must be as `postDelayed`. I updated my answer chek the code out again.

Comment: thanks for the code and reply . i tried it but still it gives me the same error and postdelayed part is still colored in red . can it be due to some codes in original source ?

Comment: thanks.checked it but didn't made any difference . also i dunno if its related or not but when i type "handler " android studio doesn't show an suggestions like the postDelayed doesn't even exist.

Comment: May be you have an SDK location problem. Does your SDK path specified correctly in your IDE? Please provide more info. What IDE do you use? What is your target SDK? Do you have the target SDK installed using Android Studio's SDK manager?

Comment: @Andy is right. Because Java has a Handler class as well. So you have to be sure that you have imported the android.os.Handler class.

Comment: currently im using sdk of android 12 and MM . api 31 and 23.SDK path is correct.my IDE is android Studio and its up to date.

Comment: it was imported and i double checked it. (import android.os.Handler;) exists in line 19 of the file.